# minor issue with this piece of code

Tags: dictionary

I am trying to add each char of a String 'ABC' to a dictionary in that order. The code I am using is:
for char in str2:
        myHashTable[char] = 0

But for some reason, the dictionary I am getting is:

{'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'B':0}

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically dictionarys are unordered.

The contents are displayed in arbitrary order, as you've found.

If you are using python look at OrderedDict:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict
>   methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys
>   were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the
>   original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and
>   reinserting it will move it to the end.